# iOS Swift 3 app rejected by App Store because of app crash in IPV6 network

Tags: swift3, app-store, ipv6, ios10.3.2

My app was rejected by App Store because it crashed in IPV6 network. This happened to me a second time. I have already updated my code to support for IPV6 network and two builds are moved successfully in that code.

But now again they raised this same issue, they said this problem only occurs on Wi-Fi network. Here is my tried code:

```
internal class Reachability
    {
        class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool
        {
            var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in6()
            zeroAddress.sin6_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
            zeroAddress.sin6_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET6)

            let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
                $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                    SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, "www.google.com")
                }
            }

            var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
            if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
                return false
            }
            let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
            let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
            return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the code that actually causes the crash. Point out the exact line causing the crash and include the complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
internal class ReachabilityCheck
{
    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool
    {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress)
        {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
                SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
            }
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false
        {
            return false
        }
        // Working for Cellular and WIFI
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        let ret = (isReachable && !needsConnection)

        return ret
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the above code work for IPv4 and IPv6 networks?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please it's working for me fine with 3g,4g and wifi network also work. the old one is not support to connectivity in mobile network.

```
class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool
    {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
          zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
       // zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
        }

        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }
```